# After rendering with OpenGL it's always rendering with OpenGL with v2.69

Tags: rendering, opengl

Just once switched to OpenGL rendering, but after that changing to Blender Render or Cycles really doesn't help. Even after quitting Blender and then re-starting it and reopening the scene, it's still rendering with OpenGL.

What could possibly go wrong?

Here's my file https://copy.com/MQ4RHuAYVvum

Comment: How are you rendering (what are you pressing)?

Comment: I'm rendering an animation. But tried to press F12 or the big Render active scene button.

Comment: Hm.. Normally those always trigger a render with cycles or whatever, I don't think it's possible to set those to render with openGL without using python or something.. Is it possible you could upload your .blend?

Comment: Here's my file - https://copy.com/MQ4RHuAYVvum

Comment: Ah, you must have rendered it to a VSE sequence.. Idk how I didn't think of it before.